# How to have discord python bot access list inside dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, discord

```py
 @commands.hybrid_command(
    name="database",
    description="This searches for database leaks",
    )
    
    async def leak(self, context:Context, term=None): 
        headers = {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "aefc8d7af6msh49bcfed5a24016dp1a349ejsn8958ff298cf1",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com"
        }
       
        if term == None:
            em = discord.Embed("FUCK")
            await context.send(embed=em)
            return
        r = requests.get("https://breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com/?func=auto&term={term}", headers=headers)
        data=json.loads(r)
```

This is my code and I'm trying to display this information:
[JSON TO DISPLAY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wilj.png)

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: im completely clueless as to what to add after data=json.loads(r) i tried somethings and nothin worked

Comment: Can you give an example for `term`? You are also not formatting your string with term, so you probably dont get the results you are expecting.

Comment: term is an email

Answer (score 0):

partially fixed by doing this i guess...

```
async def leak(self, context:Context, term=None): 

    url = "https://breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com/"
    if term == None:
        em = discord.Embed("Enter email")
        await context.send(embed=em)
        return

    querystring = {"func":"auto","term":{term}}

    headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "MY API KEY",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
    result=response['result']
    for d in result:
        #await context.send(d['password']['sha1']['hash'])  
        embed = discord.Embed(
                    title="Passwords found:",
                    description=f" **Password:** {d['password']}\n**SHA1:** {d['sha1']},\n**Hash:** {d['hash']}",
                    color=0x9C84EF
                    
                    )
        await context.send(embed=embed)
```

HOWEVER IF THE JSON RETURNS 'ERROR' AND NO DATA THE PROGRAMME CRASHES. ALSO THERE IS NO WAY TO STOP THE DISCORD BOT FROM SENDING 3000 RESULTS AND GETTING RATE LIMTED AND SPAMMING THE WHOLE CHAT...
well there isnt a way to fix any of that because i am low IQ and have 0 python knowledge

Answer (score 0):

class test(commands.Cog, name="api3"):
def **init**(self, bot):
self.bot = bot

```
    # Do your stuff here
@commands.hybrid_command(
name="database",
description="This searches for database leaks. NOTE: if nothing is found command will not work",
)

async def leak(self, context:Context, term=None): 

    url = "https://breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com/"
    if term == None:
        em = discord.Embed("Enter email")
        await context.send(embed=em)
        return

    querystring = {"func":"auto","term":{term}}

    headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "API KEY",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "breachdirectory.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring).json()
    result=response['result']
    index = 0
    while index < len(result):
        for key in result[index]:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                    title="Data collected:",
                    description=f"\n**Email: **{term}\n**Results:**{result[index]}*",
                    color=0x9C84EF
                    
                        )
        await context.send(embed=embed)
        index += 1
        if index > 5:
            await context.send("Limited to 5 results to prevent spamming")
            break
```

async def setup(bot):
await bot.add_cog(test(bot))